# How to deepcopy a Lua function using Lua C API?

Tags: c++, lua, lua-api

As the title says. In theory the right functions to use would be `lua_dump`and `lua_load`, but I've looked at their documentation and I have no idea on how to use them. What do I do? I need to deepcopy the function, because this copying will be also used to share values between stacks.

Comment: Do the functions have upvalues (including `_ENV`)?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff They may have, but if the script doesn't support upvalues, nothing bad will happen.